# How do you stop the automatic line break after templates in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

In mediawiki, whenever you embed a template into an article, it is always proceeded by a line break (as far as I know). Is there some way to prevent this so that I may place templates next to one another without the second one being on a new line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`<includeonly>` tag](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Control_template_inclusion) if you didn't already, and make sure not to put any returns in your template before the `</includeonly>`

So

```
<includeonly>This is a template. </includeonly>
```

makes {{Template}}{{Template}} output as

```
This is a template. This is a template
```

But,

```
<includeonly>This is a template. 

</includeonly>
```

makes {{Template}}{{Template}} output as

```
This is a template. 

This is a template
```

Even single returns are dangerous.  If template A contains:

```
<includeonly>{{B}}
</includeonly>
```

and template B contains:

```
<includeonly>Text
</includeonly>
```

then when you insert {{A}} into your page, both returns are subsequent and give paragraph break.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a much simpler solution than I was expecting.

Comment: This is normally enough, but sometimes you want to have multiple templates in a row, allowing some of them to return empty results,

If you, for readability, put each of them on a new line, you might still get unwanted line breaks in your article. The trick then is to use the [nowiki hack](http://smw.referata.com/wiki/Avoiding_newlines_between_template_calls): `<includeonly>{{{1|}}}<nowiki /></includeonly>`.

Ending the template with `<nowiki />` will supress any new line

Comment: In addition, if you use `<noinclude>` on the page, remove any space & line breaks you have between `<includeonly>` and `<noinclude>` as well, or you'd get the same line break problem.